# How to skip an error in a loop

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I want to skip an error (if there is any) in a loop and continue the next iteration. I want to compute 100 inverse matrices of a 2 by 2 matrix with elements randomly sampled from {0, 1, 2}. It is possible to have a singular matrix (for example,

```
1 0
2 0
```

Here is my code

```
set.seed(1)
count <- 1
inverses <- vector(mode = "list", 100)
repeat {
    x <- matrix(sample(0:2, 4, replace = T), 2, 2)
    inverses[[count]] <- solve(x)
    count <- count + 1
    if (count > 100) break
}
```

At the third iteration, the matrix is singular and the code stops running with an error message. In practice, I would like to bypass this error and continue to the next loop. I know I need to use a `try` or `tryCatch` function but I don't know how to use them. Similar questions have been asked here, but they are all really complicated and the answers are far beyond my understanding. If someone can give me a complete code specifically for this question, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This would put `NULL`s into `inverses` for the singular matrices:

```
inverses[[count]] <- tryCatch(solve(x), error=function(e) NULL)
```

If the first expression in a call to `tryCatch` raises an error, it executes and returns the value of the function supplied to its `error` argument. The function supplied to the `error` arg has to take the error itself as an argument (here I call it `e`), but you don't have to do anything with it.

You could then drop the `NULL` entries with `inverses[! is.null(inverses)]`.

Alternatively, you could use the lower level `try`. The choice is really a matter of taste.

```
count <- 0
repeat {
    if (count == 100) break
    count <- count + 1
    x <- matrix(sample(0:2, 4, replace = T), 2, 2)
    x.inv <- try(solve(x), silent=TRUE)
    if ('try-error' %in% class(x.inv)) next
    else inverses[[count]] <- x.inv
}
```

If your expression generates an error, `try` returns an object with class `try-error`. It will print the message to screen if `silent=FALSE`. In this case, if `x.inv` has class `try-error`, we call `next` to stop the execution of the current iteration and move to the next one, otherwise we add `x.inv` to `inverses`.

### Edit:

You could avoid using the `repeat` loop with `replicate` and `lapply`.

```
matrices <- replicate(100, matrix(sample(0:2, 4, replace=T), 2, 2), simplify=FALSE)
inverses <- lapply(matrices, function(mat) if (det(mat) != 0) solve(mat))
```

It's interesting to note that the second argument to `replicate` is treated as an `expression`, meaning it gets executed afresh for each replicate. This means you can use `replicate` to make a `list` of any number of random objects that are generated from the same expression.

Comment: Is there a solution that use ```tryCatch``` function or other debug function? I just had a 
 similar problem that should skip something. What is more comlicated is that I can not find a mathematical solution to solve it, so I would like to just use some debug function to fix it at once.

Answer (score 10):

`try` is just a way of telling `R`: "If you commit an error inside the following parentheses, then skip it and move on."

So if you're worried that `x <- matrix(sample(0:2, 4, replace = T), 2, 2)` might give you an error, then all you have to do is:

```
try(x <- matrix(sample(0:2, 4, replace = T), 2, 2))
```

**However**, keep in mind then that `x` will be undefined if you do this and it ends up not being able to compute the answer. That could cause a problem when you get to `solve(x)` - so you can either define `x` before `try` or just "try" the whole thing:

```
try(
      {
      x <- matrix(sample(0:2, 4, replace = T), 2, 2)
      inverses[[count]] <- solve(x)
      }
    )
```

Comment: you can assign `x` **outside** of the call to `try`, as in:  `x <- try(matrix(.etc.))`   Then test `x`'s class

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using `tryCatch` you could simply calculate the determinant of the matrix with the function `det`. A matrix is singular if and only if the determinant is zero.

Hence, you could test whether the determinant is different from zero and calculate the inverse only if the test is positive:

```
set.seed(1)
count <- 1
inverses <- vector(mode = "list", 100)
repeat {
  x <- matrix(sample(0:2, 4, replace = T), 2, 2)
  # if (det(x)) inverses[[count]] <- solve(x)
  # a more robust replacement for the above line (see comment):
  if (is.finite(determinant(x)$modulus)) inverses[[count]] <- solve(x)
  count <- count + 1
  if (count > 100) break
}
```

---

**Update**:

It is, however, possible to avoid generating singular matrices. The determinant of a 2-by-2 matrix `mat` is definded as `mat[1] * mat[4] - mat[3] * mat[2]`. You could use this knowledge for sampling random numbers. Just do not sample numbers which will produce a singular matrix. This, of course, depends on the numbers sampled before.

```
set.seed(1)
count <- 1
inverses <- vector(mode = "list", 100)

set <- 0:2 # the set of numbers to sample from

repeat {

  # sample the first value
  x <- sample(set, 1)
  # if the first value is zero, the second and third one are not allowed to be zero.
  new_set <- ifelse(x == 0, setdiff(set, 0), set)
  # sample the second and third value
  x <- c(x, sample(new_set, 2, replace = T))
  # calculate which 4th number would result in a singular matrix
  not_allowed <- abs(-x[3] * x[2] / x[1])
  # remove this number from the set
  new_set <- setdiff(0:2, not_allowed)
  # sample the fourth value and build the matrix
  x <- matrix(c(x, sample(new_set, 1)), 2, 2)

  inverses[[count]] <- solve(x)
  count <- count + 1
  if (count > 100) break
}
```

This procedure is a guarantee that all generated matrices will have an inverse.

Comment: In some cases, a matrix with determinant of zero (or really close to zero if the matrix is big) can still have an inverse matrix. For example, `A <- diag(rep(0.000000000001,1000)) det(A)`. But A is invertible.

Comment: I actually made up this simple example. The real problem is much more complicated but it also involves taking the inverse of a big matrix and sometimes `solve` gives me error messages. It is not possible to follow your update to get a non-singular matrix.

Comment: @PatrickLi If the matrix is invertible, its determinant *must* be different from zero. In your example, `A` is a non-singular matrix but due to rounding issues entailed by the small numbers, the function `det(A)` returns zero. If you have a look at `determinant(A)`, you will see the (log) determinant is different from zero. Hence, a better test than `det(A) == 0` would be `is.finite(determinant(A)$modulus)`.

Answer (score 6):

[The documentation for try](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/try.html) explains your problem pretty well. I suggest you go through it completely.

`Edit:` The documentation example looked pretty straightforward and very similar to the op's question. Thanks for the suggestion though. Here goes the answer following the example in the documentation page:

```
# `idx` is used as a dummy variable here just to illustrate that
# all 100 entries are indeed calculated. You can remove it.
set.seed(1)
mat_inv <- function(idx) {
    print(idx)
    x <- matrix(sample(0:2, 4, replace = T), nrow = 2)
    solve(x)
}
inverses <- lapply(1:100, function(idx) try(mat_inv(idx), TRUE))
```

Comment: A suggestion to read the documentation thoroughly isn't an answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but you just referred to the general function of `try` without addressing his question