# Skip occasional error in loop

Tags: r, for-loop, try-catch

I am aware that the "skip error in for loop" has been answered multiple times (see [How to skip an error in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059657/how-to-skip-an-error-in-a-loop) or [Skip Error and Continue Function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598713/skip-error-and-continue-function-in-r)). But all answers are complex and difficult to apply to a different situation for a novice.

I am performing a Gaussian histogram fitting on 100's of datasets using a piece of code.

```
results = list()
for(i in 1:length(T_files)){
  R = Table[i][,1]
  tab = data.frame(x = seq_along(R), r = R)
  res = nls(R ~ k*exp(-1/2*(x-mu)^2/sigma^2), start=c(mu=15,sigma=5, k=1) , data = tab)
  v = summary(res)$parameters[,"Estimate"]
  fun = function(x) v[3]*exp(-1/2*(x-v[1])^2/v[2]^2) 
  results[[i]] = fun(seq(0, 308, 1))/max(fun_SP(seq(0, 308, 1)))/2
}
```

The code works on most datasets when tested on each individual. However, the loop does not and shows the "error in nls(...): singular gradient" message. I want to skip this message and continue to the next dataset.

I know that a `tryCatch` function may be used, but the line containing the `nls` function is complex and I have not found a way to use correctly tryCatch in this line. Any advice is welcome :-)

Comment: I'd try using tryCatch over the nls-call. so replace `res = nls(R ~ k*exp(-1/2*(x-mu)^2/sigma^2), start=c(mu=15,sigma=5, k=1) , data = tab)` with `tryCatch(res = nls(R ~ k*exp(-1/2*(x-mu)^2/sigma^2), start=c(mu=15,sigma=5, k=1) , data = tab), next)`. I don't know if that'll work as I haven't used tryCatch before but it's worth a shot

Answer (score 2):

Use the function `try`, it allows you save an error and then put a condition `if(error==T)` then "pass to next df". Something like this:

```
error<-try(your code...)
if(class(error)!="try-error"){pass to the next one}
```

In yor case, maybe must be:

```
results = list()
for(i in 1:length(T_files)){
  R = Table[i][,1]
  tab = data.frame(x = seq_along(R), r = R)
  error = try(res <- nls(R ~ k*exp(-1/2*(x-mu)^2/sigma^2), start=c(mu=15,sigma=5, k=1) , data = tab))

    if(class(error)!="try-error"){
      v = summary(res)$parameters[,"Estimate"]
      fun = function(x) v[3]*exp(-1/2*(x-v[1])^2/v[2]^2) 
      results[[i]] = fun(seq(0, 308, 1))/max(fun_SP(seq(0, 308, 1)))/2
    }else{
      pass to next data frame (or something like that)
         }
}
```

Comment: thank you for sharing this idea. The function inside the {try} becomes an unused argument

Comment: Error in try(res = nls(R ~ k * exp(-1/2 * (x - mu)^2/sigma^2), start = c(mu = 15,  : 
  unused argument (res = nls(R ~ k * exp(-1/2 * (x - mu)^2/sigma^2), start = c(mu = 15, sigma = 5, k = 1), data = tab))

Comment: I know what happen, you must use `<-` instead of `=` inside the function because they take it like an argument of the function. I edited the answer.

Comment: Please @Gabriel123, if the answer is good, please give it like good. It will help me a lot.

Comment: sorry I was trying it over and over again. No I'm afraid that the issue did not get solved. I must have entered it wrong - I conclude your code simply by ... }else{ next }, hope that makes sense

Comment: Do you mean after `if(class(error)`? When you use the function `try`, it can return a `"try-error`. What I am doing is "when the error is different (`!=`) to `$try-error`$ do the next process. Generally, the symbol `!` in R means "not"